# How to create diagonal array from existing array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, diagonal

I am trying to make a diagonal numpy array from:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Expected result:

```
[[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
 [ 0,  0,  0,  2,  0],
 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  3],
 [ 4,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [ 0,  5,  0,  0,  0],
 [ 0,  0,  6,  0,  0],
 [ 0,  0,  0,  7,  0],
 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  8],
 [ 9,  0,  0,  0,  0]]
```

What would be an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What's the relation between your input and expected output? have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What are the input parameters apart from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to set the specified elements of the output:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> arr = np.zeros((9, 5), dtype=int)           # create empty array
>>> arr[np.arange(9), np.arange(2,11) % 5] = a  # insert a 
>>> arr
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
       [9, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: `np.fill_diagonal` has a `wrap` mode like this, but it only works for the main diagonal.  The other `diag` functions allow offsets, but no wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by `np.fill_diagonal` which can wrap, but not offset:

```
In [308]: arr=np.zeros((9,5),int)
In [309]: arr.flat[2:45:6]=np.arange(1,10)
In [310]: arr
Out[310]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 8]])
```

(though for some reason this has the 4th all zero row).

```
def fill_diagonal(a, val, wrap=False):
    ...       
    step = a.shape[1] + 1
    # Write the value out into the diagonal.
    a.flat[:end:step] = val
```

Comment: you lost the `9` and the fourth row seem wrong. Using a `step` works great until you have one value in the last column and expect the next value in the next row, first column :)

Comment: Yes, I"m puzzled about that.  I'll leave the answer up in case someone sees the flaw in this 'strided' solution.

Comment: well, the flaw is that you need different "steps". 6 for row 1->2, 2->3, 4->5, 5->6, 6->7, 7->8 but only 1 for row 3->4 and 8->9.

Comment: This style of wrapping was the default for `fill_diagonal` until a version 1.6.

Comment: So when lined up just right the stride of 6 skips a whole row of length 5.